# Website Has too many Redirect Loop

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

Everyone,

i have my ssl certificate installed on https://www.copierextravaganza.com but my actual domain the website runs is on https://copierextravaganza.com ... to make my ssl visible i used 301 redirect by modifying htaccess ... after implementing the code, whenever i open the website it does not load up and shows error website has too many redirects ..

is there some error in the htaccess code below ?

my website is on wordpress

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^copierextravaganza\.com$ [NC]    
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.copierextravaganza.com/ [R=301,L]    
RewriteRule ^author/(privacy)/?$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]    
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]    
</IfModule>    
# END WordPress
```

Please advice thanks

Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

I think if the site_url option (see settings/general in the wordpress dashboard) is set to http://domain.com and you access it from http://www.domain.com then it will 301 redirect you to http://domain.com. You're effectively forcing the site to redirect you *back* to http://www.domain.com, causing a loop. The best thing to do would be to either change your site url to http://www.domain.com, or get SSL certification for the domain without the www

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jamie, I have already tried changing wordpress base url from the admin end, config file and database as well, upon doin the same i simply end up at 501 internal server error !! thanks for the input though !!